# Passing shared_ptr as an argument to thread function, results into an error

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, ref

I am trying to do something similar as below:

```
std::shared_ptr<asengine::PreCompileConfig> precompileconfigobj = std::make_shared<asengine::PreCompileConfig>();

std::thread rsync_t(&asengine::PreCompile::RunRsyncDb, precompileconfigobj));
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1697:61: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (asengine::PreCompile::*)(const std::shared_ptr<asengine::PreCompileConfig>&)>(std::reference_wrapper<std::shared_ptr<asengine::PreCompileConfig> >)>'
   typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                         ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1727:9: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (asengine::PreCompile::*)(const std::shared_ptr<asengine::PreCompileConfig>&)>(std::reference_wrapper<std::shared_ptr<asengine::PreCompileConfig> >)>'
     _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
```

After brief research, I could find out that thread function expects reference of the argument object, instead of value.

```
std::thread rsync_t(&asengine::PreCompile::RunRsyncDb, std::ref(precompileconfigobj));
```

But still, it doesn't solve the problem. Any help to figure out the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Show declaration of `RunRsyncDb` method. I guess it is `static` then you don't need to pass `precompileconfigobj` as param.

Comment: @rafix07 void RunRsyncDb(const std::shared_ptr<PreCompileConfig>& shptrprecompileconfigobj, const std::shared_ptr<Logger>& slog);

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem. I had to pass the object through which thread function is going to be called.

```
std::thread rsync_t(&asengine::PreCompile::RunRsyncDb, precompileobj, std::ref(precompileconfigobj));
```